# Prove that there is no surjective function from the reals to the set of functions with no fixed points

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove using the diagonal method that there is no surjective function $ g \colon \mathbb {R} \to C$ where $$C = \{f \colon \mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R} \mid \forall x \in \mathbb {R} ,\  f(x) \neq x\}.$$

I'm given a hint: Construct a function $h \colon \mathbb {R} \times \mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R} $ such that $ \forall x,y \in \Bbb {R}$, $h(x, y) \notin \{x,y\} $.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $C$ was just a set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, would you know what to do?

Comment: If C was set of all functions then I can find a surjective function from R→(R→R)

Comment: Are you sure? A surjective function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Adayah What do you mean by ${\Bbb {R}}^{\Bbb {R}}$, the notation doesn't make any sense!

Comment: I thought it was proven by Cantor that they have the same cardinality.

Comment: @ThatIs $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is the set of all function $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. More generally, if $X,Y$ are sets then $Y^X$ is the set of all functions $X\to Y$.

Comment: @Thatls : actually it does make sense ! OP : no Cantor proved precisely the opposite !

Comment: Moshe, if you can find a surjection from $\Bbb R$ on the set of *all* functions, surely you can find a surjection onto this set.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Any idea for this question?

Comment: Sure; coming back to my original hint: try analyzing the proof (by Cantor) that there is no surjection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ and think how to adjust it so that it fits to your case.

Comment: Thank you Adayah. I have been thinking about this way for almost an hour, but the thing is I can disprove the surjectiveness of such function. Cantor just skips element by element but I can't do that here